# sql injection attack or vulnerability? Where can i find list of web application vulnerabilities and attack types ?

Tags: web-application, attacks, vulnerability, owasp, owasp-top-ten

I can't separate OWASP Top-10 security risks, Sql Injection is attack or vulnerability ? If Sql injection is web application attack type(and other owasp security risks), then where can i find vulnerabilities list ?

Comment: SQL injection is an attack which is done by using an existing vulnerability in the application. There is no list of all applications vulnerable to SQL injection attacks but a [simple search](https://www.cvedetails.com/vulnerability-list/opsqli-1/sql-injection.html) will give you some examples of vulnerable applications.

Comment: Thanks, i think i couldn't explain my question, sorry, but I'm searching list of web application vulnerabilities and web application attacks, I read 
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Vulnerability and https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Category:Attack, I don't need all vulnerabilities and all attack types, it's enough 10 or more.

Comment: In case of SQL injection: the vulnerability is to pass user input inside SQL statements to the database without proper validation or quoting. The SQL injection attack is using this vulnerability to execute attacker controlled SQL statements this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL injection is both ;) Attack and vulnerability. Its usually primarily caused by the improper input validation vulnerability. But also, it can be caused by wrong application design as there are techniques allowing mitigation of improper input validation.

If you need just 10 check OWASP top 10 vulnerabilities. I would say that exactly what you are looking for.